# firefox - customize scroll bar

Tags: css

i have the following code that customizes a webkit scroll bar....

```
/*webkit scroll bar*/  

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0); 
}
```

what i would like to do is customize the scrollbar of a page loaded in firefox the same way... for which i tried the following code..

```
/*mozilla scroll bar*/  

::-moz-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}


::-moz-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-moz-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0); 
}
```

but it does not work..... how can i customize the scrollbar in the same way i did for webkit... any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Firefox doesn't have anything like that (and besides, you didn't even convert all of the prefixes).

Comment: so... basically what you're trying to say is i can't do it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't because of [bug #77790](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790) (Link#1).

> Bug 77790 - (scrollbar-colors) Style the scrollbar (binding ::-moz-horizontal-scrollbar to XBL)\

The only way is to use jQuery. I don't know how to code it, so don't ask me. I prepared the following links for jQuery scrollbars. [Click here!](http://plugins.jquery.com/custom-scrollbar/)(Link#2)

Links:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790
- http://plugins.jquery.com/custom-scrollbar/

Answer (score 6):

FireFox support these two:

1. scrollbar-width : auto|thin|none...
2. scrollbar-color

Answer (score 0):

for firefox now you can use this

```
.element{
 scrollbar-width: thin;
 scrollbar-color: blue transparent;

}
```

where blue is for the thumb and transparent for the track